# a difference of line break occuring in horizontal Form Layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

i have to create a form which contains a lot of label and forms like text area ,radio etc.but when i apply bootzstrap horizontal form method it is giving one line difference between label and text area here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
    </script> 
    <script type="text/javascript"
     src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
    </script>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
  Promo description *
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
  </form>
  </body>
<html>
```

and the one line difference here is the screen shot how to make label and textarea perfectly horizontal ??any guideline 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Define in css `margin-top: -10px;` or something like that?
Guess that will put it next to your text aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You should follow the format described in [Forms](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms).

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
  <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label">Promo description *</label>
    <div class="controls">
      <textarea rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```